# Cassandra: With 10 nodes in a ring and with a replication factor of 3 what is probability of getting quorum (2 nodes) if 3 nodes are down?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, replication, permutation, probability

Or in general:

Let's say we have a cluster of n nodes and every piece of data is replicated on k nodes. And our quorum is calculated as (k+1) / 2. And our data is equally distributed.

Let's say m nodes wend down. So, what will be a probability of not getting a quorum (request hits (k+1) / 2 nodes which are down) and what percent of all request will face this problem?

Here is example for 5 nodes and replication factor of 3:

With 5 nodes and replication factor 3 we will have 10 possible groups of 3 servers:
a b c d e

Groups:
a b c
a b d
a b e
a c d
a d e
a c e
a d e
b c d
b c e
c d e

1) a is down, so 7 groups are affected, but we need quorum of 2 so cluster is still up and serving data.

2) a and b are down. 9 groups are affected but only a b c, a b d, a b e lost 2 servers and can't serve data. So, 30% of cluster is down.

3) a, b and c are down. All groups are affected but only  a b c, a b d, a b e,  a c d, a c e, b c d, b c e lost 2 or 3 nodes. So, 70% of cluster is down.

4) a, b, c, d - 100% is down.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which nodes are down and how your keys are distributed across the nodes.  Best case, 100% of your data is accessible, worst case 70%.

Comment: Yes, it will be 70%. I can calculate it by writing down all the permutations. But what is the formula?  100 nodes, replication factor 7, 4 nodes in a quorum and 23 nodes down - how to mathematically calculate it?

Comment: Actually, not sure if it is 70%.

Comment: @Alex If the down nodes are all adjacent, then it is impossible to get quorum across 3 ranges.  Assuming even data distribution, 3 out of 10 inaccessible ranges  means you have 70% availability. If they are not adjacent, you could still have 100% availability.